# Jssor How do I make it so the text box within the slider doesn't scale with the screen size. I still want to parent object to scale?

Tags: textbox, scale, jssor, fixed-size-types

When the slider is scaled down with screen size, the child element that contains a text box also scales down in size, making the text unreadable on smaller screens. I would like only the text box to remain it's original size.

I have tried setting the child element to a fixed pixel width/height, and that didn't work, not even with a !important after the width and height setting.